# iRedMail email server is not working in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mail-server, linode

Hi i have installed iredmail-0.8.1 server in ubuntu 12.04 in Linode server. so installation gone well without errors.
after installation when i am trying to access mail server or cpanel (http://fqdn.linode.com/mail/ or https://fqdn.linode.com/iredadmin/) pages are not loading atall.

can anybody tell me what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem you had. To fix the problem, you have to edit "/etc/apache2/conf.d/roundcubemail.conf" and edit the  entry to:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail/">
    Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Reload the apache daemon and you are good to go!